# Seeding based on hashing is deprecated

Tags: python, random, seed

The below function collects random numbers but the `seed` parameter should be optional. Therefore, I added the `*` .

```
import random

def random_num(n, number, *seed): #n is the number of values to return and number is the range of the uniform distribution that uses later
    collect = []
    random.seed(seed)
    for i in range(n):
        collect.append(round(random.uniform(-number, number),2))    
    return collect
```

Running the function without using the `seed` parameter:

```
random_num(4,5)
```

The result is: `[4.82, -3.12, -0.62, 0.27]` which looks fine I guess. It also shows the warning below:

> DeprecationWarning: Seeding based on hashing is deprecated since
> Python 3.9 and will be removed in a subsequent version. The only
> supported seed types are: None, int, float, str, bytes, and bytearray.
> random.seed(seed)

What is the proper way to simply make the seed parameter optional without issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just default the seed to 'None'

```
def random_num(n, number, seed=None): 
    random.seed(seed)
    [...]
```

This then uses the default seed (current system time)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: Interesting. What do you think about setting `seed = False`. When would be used?

Comment: It depends what behaviour you want.  `None` will use the default source of randomness for the seed,  `False` will set the seed to 0 (so you will always get the same results.)

Comment: any info on what the warning was about?

Comment: If you use *seed , then seed is always a tuple, it may be an empty tuple.  random.seed no longer accepts tuples as an argument